What's the correct postgres url when hosting Supabase with Coolify?
Can't figure out what is the correct postgres url when hosting with Coolify. Everything is up and running. I have only changed the service name to db and kong domain to https://mywebsite.com:8000
Coolify is hosted on ubuntu vps_1 and through Coolify I deployed Supabase on ubuntu vps_2
What's the correct postgres url?
npx supabase db push --db-url "postgres://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"

docker-compose.yml
.env.example
My environment variables:
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=supabase-db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
SERVICE_PASSWORD_POSTGRES=***


With the default Coolify Docker Compose File its as followed:
Right under supabase-db (inside the Docker Compose File) you add the mapping (ports:) like that:
  supabase-db:
    ports:
     - '${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}'
    image: ...

Then under Firewall i.e. Hetzner you allow Port: 5432
Then you construct your url like the following:
postgresql://postgres:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@supabase-db:5432/postgres


Thanks, this worked. But I'm curious what this "Make it publicly available" checkbox under supabase-db settings means, connection works but it is unchecked.

your url is correct
npx supabase db push --db-url "postgres://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
but you need to add port mapping in the compose file under the supabase-db image
like
ports:
     - '5432:5050'
     - '9001:9001'

this worked for me
thought the port is soppose to map to database port to 5050
it did not but worked in the default port 5432.so do this exactly and use the same url with port 5432

Edit the docker-compose file using the button: Edit Docker Compose
the button is located beside Service Stack
In the supabase-db section add the mapping:
ports:
  - '5433:5432'

This will expose the 5433
Example of JDBC connection:
jdbc:postgresql://user:pass@<your_ip>:5433/postgres

Remember to enable the 5433 port in your firewall if you have one.
